# ASP.NET MVC Method being called twice

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

We have an controller method that is being called twice. The first time it is called we get the correct parameters, the second time it is called we get no parameters and the MVC engine throws an exception because the arguments to the method cannot be null.

We have seen this behaviour before when using certain versions of Safari and it was to do with  authentication. When using windows authentication if the properties of the authentication in IIS were set to Negotiate and NTLM an ajax call would get sent once for each. The fix for this was to remove one (I think we just left it as NTLM). This is not the case as we are using forms authentication here.

We have also seen similar behaviour when calling WCF methods that were returning types that were derived and not using the KnownType attributes on the parent class.

We cannot reproduce this with any success (it's happening infrequently on a clients machine) and are looking for any general gotchas.

Comment: Could you show the calling javascript code that performs the AJAX request?

Comment: standard jquery ajax request..(haven't got the code in front of me now)

Comment: Could you then go ahead and get the code in front of you and post it here?

Comment: i'm at home at the moment and the code is at work, but we are also seeing this behaviour on a controller method that returns a view (it's not always ajax)

Comment: How is this controller action invoked? Hyperlink? Form post? What do you see in the IIS logs?

Comment: I am currently having the same issue on a project where in the Edit/Id method is called and then exactly .2 seconds later, Edit with no Id is called and an error is ELMAH logged.  We cannot find any AJAX or other items that would call this (Edit/Id is never an AJAX target) and we also cannot reproduce for anything - but it doesn't seem to be affecting the end users as far as we can tell.  Interested to see if this generates any responses

Comment: @Tommy we too have found out about this through the elmah log, are you using Windows Authentication?

Comment: @AranMulholland - nope, forms authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the call is being called twice is because of a bug in Safari when working with Windows Authentication under IIS. Go to the Authentication settings of your website. Right click on Windows Authentication, choose providers and remove Negotiate, leaving NTLM which works fine. I haven't tested Kerberos.

This issue only appears in certain builds of safari.

Comment: Randomly from the future, but, in your initial question, you said you were using forms authentication but your answer addresses windows authentication.  Does this mean that IIS Windows Authentication can impact forms authentication.  I have tracked our issue down to IE8 only, but since it doesnt impact the users, I havent spent a lot of resources on it.  Happen to see my "favorited" question list and that this one had an answer.  Any additional insights you have on the forms auth would be most welcome.

Comment: @Tommy no interaction that I know of between forms and windows auth in IIS. Sorry.